# Using Visible Elements for jQuery Form Validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

The fields in my form already validate. If they're invalid, there's a span class that appears and informs the user. Likewise if they're empty.

So I thought it would be easy enough to just check for the visibility of one of these classes.

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (($('.error').length) || ($('.empty').length)) {

      function validateReview(){

               document.getElementById('ReviewForm').submit();
      }

  } else {

      function validateReview(){

                alert("Please check fields and be sure to leave a review.");
      }

  }
};
```

And then the submit button in my form simply calls `validateReview()` onclick.

But it's not working how I expected, I get this as an error "**validateReview is not defined**".
Did I declare `validateReview()` incorrectly, or in a local scope maybe? BIG newb here so please be aware. I know enough only to get in trouble.

Comment: You spelled `validateReview()` as `validatReview()`. Two times. Now you see what you did, right?

Comment: I spelled it wrong in the question, it is correct in the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your logic but whatevar it is I think you can use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.error').length || $('.empty').length) {
        $('#ReviewForm')[0].submit();
    } else {
        alert("Please check fields and be sure to leave a review.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried that. Form still doesn't submit and I'm still getting the "validateReview is not defined" error

Comment: You have to submit the form using a submit handler, how you are submiting it ?

Comment: normally it calls a submit function in the forms script I have. Other forms in this file use this `document.getElementById('formID').submit();` which is placed in the onclick of the submit button.

Comment: Then you should use `$('#formID').on('submit', function(e){ if ($('.error').length || $('.empty').length).... })`

Comment: In the forms.js script? Cause that script handles multiple forms so I need to keep this "inline" if you will.

Comment: Actually how you are submitting your form, can you give me the code ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13427/discussion-between-frankv-and-sheikh-heera)